# Conditionally insert an item into a dynamodb table using boto3 The conditional request failed

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want insert in dynamo only if an other item is all ready exist but I have this error:

```
An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) when calling the PutItem operation: The conditional request failed
```

My boto3 code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('my_table_dev')
try:
    conditionalUpdateResponse = table.put_item(
        Item={
            'event_id': 1,
            'timestamp': 1538586609,
            'bit_value': 6,
            'category': 'alarm',
            'edt_id': 3684824,
            'equipment_id': 3440153,
            'event_date': '2018-10-03T17:10:09',
            'event_type_id': 35,
            'event_type_name': 'Others',
            'event_val': 1,
            'location_id': 3405207
        },
        ConditionExpression='attribute_exists(#equipment_id) AND attribute_exists(#edt_id) AND attribute_exists(#location_id)',
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#equipment_id": "equipment_id", "#edt_id": "edt_id", "#location_id": "location_id"}
    )
except dynamodb.meta.client.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException as e: 
    print(e)
```

**EDIT**

if I remove `ConditionExpression` insert is always OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `my_table_dev` is defined with `event_id` as partition key and `timestamp` as sort key, the above command works perfectly well with the `ConditionExpression` if the record with `'event_id': 1` and `'timestamp': 1538586609` already exists.  The `ConditionExpression` checks if the three attributes are there and then the above command *updates the existing record*.

Further, assuming that you essentially intend the command to perform an SQL-like action on DynamoDB (which it cannot do, generally speaking), the solution would be to create a global secondary index with `equipment_id` and partition key and either `edt_id` or `location_id` as a sort key, then query this index to see if a relevant record exists and then perform a `put_item` (without `ConditionExpression`) if it does.

Hope this helps.